# JQuery Modal height in IE

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery dialog applied on a div. The content of the div varies dynamically. I have set the height to 400 px and it works fine in Firefox and all other browsers except IE. 
In IE, The dialog box shrinks. I don't want to make the dialog re-sizable.
This is how I have declared my dialog

```
$('#dialog_div').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable:false,
    width: 800,
    height :400
});
```

and this is how I am calling this div:

```
$('#dialog_div').dialog('open');
```

Can you please suggest how I can make it work in IE??

NOTE: there was a fix in jquery site to make the height fixed in IE. I tried to use that, but it doesn't allow the scroll bars in the modal and all the div looks like a mess inside the div.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the last comma in the function options.

```
...
height :400
});
```